# Delete column in SQL Server after a period from creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate, t-sql

I am working with sensitive/private files stored in SQL Server as VarBinary(MAX). Is there a way to tell the database or nHibernate to nullify the column after a period of time after its creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to put a timestamp column on the table, then set up a SQL Scheduled Job with a query to delete those rows periodically based on that time.

Comment: just to clarify; a timestamp is a datatype in SQL Server that has nothing to with time.  You meant a datetime column :)

Comment: No, I wasn't using timestamp as a datatype.  Just as a general concept.  A timestamp being a stored date/time value when something occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not

Imagine the fun when SQL Server decides to change data *apparently on it's own* because the code monkey fluffed setting up whatever mechanism would be used...

You could (off top of my head):

- Encrypt the columns
- Schedule a clean up (SQL Agent job, a config table)
- Don't use SQL Server for the files themselves, just store paths/links